# C++ Builder - Creating a TCP Server Connection programmatically with TIdTCPServer

Tags: c++, tcp, c++builder, indy

I need to implement a   `TCP Server`    connection with    `TIdTCPServer`   component.
I already did it with `GUI` (drag & drop) and its working. But I need to Split form and  `TCP`   implementations. Example codes I've seen so far always uses   `TIdTCPServer`  as the member of  `TForm`  class.(result of drag and drop).

How I Call `TCPConnection` class that I've implemented from the TForm

```
TCPConnection CConnection = new TCPConnection(Owner, this);
```

Here is how I try to create a  `TCP Server`   Connection.

```
TCPConnection::TCPConnection(TComponent* Owner, TForm4* TSuperForm){
    IdTCPServer1 = new TIdTCPServer(Owner);
    IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Clear();
    //IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Add()->SetBinding("10.10.2.103", 774);

    IdTCPServer1->OnConnect = (TIdServerThreadEvent)(&OnConnect);
    IdTCPServer1->OnExecute = (TIdServerThreadEvent)&OnExecute;
    IdTCPServer1->OnDisconnect = (TIdServerThreadEvent)&OnConnect;
    IdTCPServer1->OnException =  (TIdServerThreadExceptionEvent)&OnException;
     IdTCPServer1->DefaultPort = 774;
    IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Add();
    IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Items[0]->IP="10.10.2.103";
    IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Items[0]->Port=774; 


    IdTCPServer1->ListenQueue = 15;
    IdTCPServer1->MaxConnections = 15;
    IdTCPServer1->TerminateWaitTime = 5000;
    IdTCPServer1->Active = true;



    this->TSuperForm = TSuperForm;

}
```

So far that codes work. But when I try to reach the context, connection is lost and `throws`  an exception

```
void TCPConnection::OnConnect(TIdContext *AContext){
    String IP = AContext->Binding()->PeerIP;
}

void TCPConnection::OnException(TIdContext *AContext, Exception *AException)

{
    ShowMessage("Error:" + AException->ToString());    
}
```

`Error` says `TIdTaskThreadWork` (I'll edit error, might be wrong)
If I don't try to reach AContext, connection stays without problem.

Might be something about thread, locking list, ...

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Normally there's no need to access the `Bindings` property all, unless you only want to serve on one particular interface. Just set DefaultPort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those function casts look very smelly. Are you sure you've defined the functions as `__fastcall`, as the function casts should not be required at all.

This should be all you need, if you've defined them correctly.

```
IdTCPServer1->OnConnect = &OnConnect;
// ... etc...
```

Comment: The type-casts are indeed problematic and are masking compiler error messages.

Comment: yes, the problem was __fastcall. I had declared them as void functionName; Now it works after I added __fastcall. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
TIdTCPServer *TCPServer = new TIdTCPServer( this );
TCPServer->Active = false;
TCPServer->OnExecute = MyExecute;
TCPServer->DefaultPort = XXX;
TCPServer->Active = true;
```

Then my MyExecute call is defined like this:

```
void __fastcall MyExecute( TIdContext* AContext );
```

Other callbacks are handled the same way, don't forget __fastcall and it should work.

Comment: I think `Active` defaults to false anyway.

Comment: I believe it does too, but I always make it false on creation.  habit :-)